# In Flutter, ExoPlayer is not working for some video URL which get from API

Tags: flutter, exoplayer, flutter-video-player

I have this type of video URL: https://devnuevo.com/media/video/demo_720.mp4
The problem is, that when I try to play this video it using ExoPlayer, the following exception is thrown.
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)

https://devnuevo.com/media/video/demo_720.mp4

Comment: Can you share on which platform do you run this plan?

Comment: have you tried with other players? That url has a security risk label because it's not really secure and the SSL signature maybe expired or not even there.

Comment: @Anmol Mishra- I made an OTT media service app in flutter where I used 
 "chewie: ^1.3.0" & "video_player: ^2.2.19" for playing video. But only play some secure links which I get from API. And I used flutter-2.8.1 to run this plan.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla did not try yet with another player. But I used the same media player in the Native android project and the same video link work properly there. but in the flutter project, only a secure link plays properly but this type of insecure link throws this exception. Is there any solution that I can play any kind of secure or insecure video URL can play?

Comment: please if you solved it, could you share the solution?